# Resting Activity intent Values after press back and selecting another Button?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to pass Recipe name and Content and image to another activity by put them in extras "PutStringExtra", and using Bundle for images.

it's work fine for the first time only the data passed well but when i click back and click on another Recipe it's Shows the same as the last one!
so how i can clear The Data From the extras?

Main Activity Code:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),recipe.class);

    //Recipe How to content
    final String recipeA=getString(R.string.recipeA);
    final String recipeB=getString(R.string.recipeB);
    final String recipeD=getString(R.string.recipeD);
    final String recipeAName=getString(R.string.recipeAName);
    final String recipeBName=getString(R.string.recipeBName);
    final String recipeDName=getString(R.string.recipeDName);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
public void onItemClick(View view, int i) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            intent.putExtra("recipeA",recipeA);
                            intent.putExtra("recipeAName",recipeAName);
                            bundle.putInt("imageA",R.drawable.a);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            intent.putExtra("recipeB",recipeB);
                            intent.putExtra("recipeBName",recipeBName);
                            bundle.putInt("imageB",R.drawable.b);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            intent.putExtra("recipeD",recipeD);
                            intent.putExtra("recipeDName",recipeDName);
                            bundle.putInt("imageD",R.drawable.d);
                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
```

Second Activity Code:

```
intent= getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();


    if (intent.hasExtra("recipeA")) {
        String recipeA = intent.getStringExtra("recipeA");
        String recipeAName = intent.getStringExtra("recipeAName");
        recipeContent.setText(recipeA);
        recipeName.setText(recipeAName);
        int imageA= bundle.getInt("imageA");
        mImageView.setImageResource(imageA);
        intent.removeExtra("recipeA");

    }
    else if (intent.hasExtra("recipeB")) {

        String recipeB = intent.getStringExtra("recipeB");
        String recipeBName = intent.getStringExtra("recipeBName");
        recipeContent.setText(recipeB);
        recipeName.setText(recipeBName);
        int imageB= bundle.getInt("imageB");
        mImageView.setImageResource(imageB);

    }
    else if (intent.hasExtra("recipeD")) {

        String recipeD = intent.getStringExtra("recipeD");
        String recipeDName = intent.getStringExtra("recipeDName");
        recipeContent.setText(recipeD);
        recipeName.setText(recipeDName);
        int imageD= bundle.getInt("imageD");
        mImageView.setImageResource(imageD);
    }
```

Comment: Please remove final keyword from Intent and Bundle and try

Comment: @JinsLukose It has nothing to do with the final.  Final only makes the reference immutable, not the object it refers to.

Comment: I think problem here is bundle object. Create bundle object whenever launch the new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Intent each time.  There's no reason to reuse the same Intent.

Also, don't mix calls to add extras to a Bundle with calls to put extras to the Intent like that.  Use one or the other.  The Intent.putExtraXXX will call bundle.putExtraXXX on its own Bundle.  Setting a bundle may then wipe out those things you already set.  Either set everything in the Bundle then add the bundle, or set everything on the Intent.  The second is more normal.